# How to solve for $x \times x = y$ when I know $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out a problem for a program I'm writing.  I am calculating color values, and they get premultiplied by the alpha.  I want to figure out what the alpha *was* before hand and divide the color by that.

I have the new premultiplied alpha (let's say alpha is $.25$ or $25\%$)

$\alpha = .25 * .25$;

$\alpha = .0625$

Given this information, I want to figure out $.25$ from $.0625$

$.0625 = x \times x$

My math is super bad/rusty.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you know what a square root is?...

Comment: Ah, easy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Cure's suggestion:

sqrt(.0625) does what I want!

*EDIT: For those curious, you can see the related issue I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346585/opengl-render-to-texture-with-partial-transparancy-translucency-and-then-rende

This solved my problem 100%.